# How to send touch event to camera activity

Tags: android, events, camera, touch, inject

I'm trying to start the camera activity from my application

```
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

thats ok, after few seconds (lets say 10) I want to dispatch the touch event
and simulate the operation of taking a picture (long touch on the screen).

after that I want to catch the result back in my app...

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

do you have any idea how can I perform that?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you cannot send a touch event to another app. Even if you could, it would not help, as there are thousands of camera apps, which use a variety of trigger mechanisms for taking a picture.

Either allow the user to take the picture, or you will need to work with the camera hardware in your own app, rather than use a third-party app.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :)
What if I'll take the camera's source code and use reflection for some mothods to trigger the picture shot,
Is that possible??